# Towards building a good career profile

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs

Since I am not really sure if I will [leave my country or not](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/2015/12/19/why-i-stayed-in-greece-2015/), I saw some decent jobs in SO, so I would like to make sure my profile is good to go. This way, if I stay and decline a PhD offer, I can apply right away.

In my [CV](https://gsamaras.files.wordpress.com/2016/05/cv.pdf), I have a *work experience* section. There I haven't listed my first real job, working as a waiter in a very busy place. A recruiter that I was talking to lately saw that from the section *Why me?* and told me that I should list that in the work experience, since it adds info about myself.

**Should I add to my CV here that I have worked as waiter?** I haven't, since it's irrelevant to the field of Informatics and Telecommunications.

Comment: So, you're saying your experience as a waiter can't help you design an system to analyze customers' cell phone obsession while dining :)

Comment: @PetahChristian haha, good point. I am just asking if it is usual to include our non related (to the job we will apply) work experiences!

Comment: Why do you think it's unrelated? Two words: transferable skills.

Comment: Dealing with (possibly angry) customers (clients) in the right way is a good skill to have if you are every dealing with customers or clients in the future - some examples: helpdesk, tech support, management. The customers could be other departments (divisions) of the same company. Remember customers are people and good people skills are valuable.

Comment: I would not worry about adding a waiter skill, your resume is not lacking for achievements at all. The only potential improvement I can imagine is adding some more human voice up front. This is a matter of style and opinion and I offer it only as an option. For some guidance on how to do this, see http://www.forbes.com/sites/lizryan/2014/07/17/how-to-write-your-human-voiced-resume

Comment: Good question, but wouldn't it belong on [workplace.se] rather than SO Meta? That you saw decent jobs on SO seems not more than tangential to the topic.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's it and that should be an answer! David, hell yeah! The place I was working was the hottest place in the "Miami of Greece" and most of the customers were *very* rich and/or famous, which lead to grumpy behaviors occasionally, so you are correct! Paul, I am not sure what `some more human voice up front` means, can you expand? das-g, that was the question I was facing when posting. But then because of the jobs in SO, I thought I should post here, wrongly obviously. Should I post in the workplace too, since the question is delete here?